# Organizing array of objects using specific object's field value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I am having an array of objects which is structured like below

const data = [
{
depth:0,
id:1,
name:"data 1"
},
{
depth:0,
id:2,
name:"data 2"
},
{
depth:0,
id:3,
name:"data 3"
},
{
depth:1,
id:11,
name:"data 11",
parentid:1,
},
{
depth:1,
id:12,
name:"data 12",
parentid:1,
},
{
depth:1,
id:21,
name:"data 21",
parentid:2,
},
{
depth:1,
id:31,
name:"data 31",
parentid:3,
},
{
depth:2,
id:111,
name:"data 111",
parentid:11,
},
{
depth:2,
id:112,
name:"data 112",
parentid:11,
},
{
depth:2,
id:113,
name:"data 113",
parentid:11,
},
{
depth:2,
id:121,
name:"data 121",
parentid:12,
},
{
depth:2,
id:122,
name:"data 122",
parentid:12,
},
{
depth:2,
id:211,
name:"data 211",
parentid:21,
},
{
depth:3,
id:2111,
name:"data 2111",
parentid:211,
},
{
depth:3,
id:2112,
name:"data 2112",
parentid:211,
}]

I want the output like below

```
const output= [
    {
        depth:0,
        id:1,
        name:"data 1",
        childs:[
            {
                depth:1,
                id:11,
                name:"data 11",
                parentid:1,
                childs:[
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:111,
                        name:"data 111",
                        parentid:11,
                    },
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:112,
                        name:"data 112",
                        parentid:11,
                    },
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:113,
                        name:"data 113",
                        parentid:11,
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                depth:1,
                id:12,
                name:"data 12",
                parentid:1,
                childs:[
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:121,
                        name:"data 121",
                        parentid:12,
                    },
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:122,
                        name:"data 122",
                        parentid:12,
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        depth:0,
        id:2,
        name:"data 2",
        childs:[
            {
                depth:1,
                id:21,
                name:"data 21",
                parentid:2,
                childs:[
                    {
                        depth:2,
                        id:211,
                        name:"data 211",
                        parentid:21,
                        childs:[
                            {
                                depth:3,
                                id:2111,
                                name:"data 2111",
                                parentid:211,
                            },
                            {
                                depth:3,
                                id:2112,
                                name:"data 2112",
                                parentid:211,
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        depth:0,
        id:3,
        name:"data 3",
        childs:[
            {
                depth:1,
                id:31,
                name:"data 31",
                parentid:3,
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

1. Key factor to achieve this output is depth,id,parentid
2. Each childs array of objects's parentid should be match their parent id.
   I had tried some map,filter,for loop methods but it's not working as I  expected. How can i achieve this output in Javascript?

Comment: you can use `Array.sort()` [Here](https://dev.to/banesag/sorting-arrays-of-strings-in-javascript-2g11#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%20arrays%20have%20a,items%20into%20an%20alphabetical%20order.&text=The%20sort(%20)%20method%20accepts%20an,based%20on%20the%20elements%20values.) is a link to some examples using it. You should filter the array first with `Array.filter()` to get the objects on specific depth so then you can sort them.

Comment: Is the `data` sorted by depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const createTree = data => {
  const initials = data.filter(d => !d.parentid)
  
  const loop = (item) => {
    const childs = data.filter(d => d.parentid === item.id)
    
    if(!childs.length){
      return item
    }
    
    return {
      ...item,
      childs: childs.map(loop)
    }
  }
  
  
  return initials.map(loop)
  
}




const data = [ { depth:0, id:1, name:"data 1" }, { depth:0, id:2, name:"data 2" }, { depth:0, id:3, name:"data 3" }, { depth:1, id:11, name:"data 11", parentid:1, }, { depth:1, id:12, name:"data 12", parentid:1, }, { depth:1, id:21, name:"data 21", parentid:2, }, { depth:1, id:31, name:"data 31", parentid:3, }, { depth:2, id:111, name:"data 111", parentid:11, }, { depth:2, id:112, name:"data 112", parentid:11, }, { depth:2, id:113, name:"data 113", parentid:11, }, { depth:2, id:121, name:"data 121", parentid:12, }, { depth:2, id:122, name:"data 122", parentid:12, }, { depth:2, id:211, name:"data 211", parentid:21, }, { depth:3, id:2111, name:"data 2111", parentid:211, }, { depth:3, id:2112, name:"data 2112", parentid:211, }]

const tree = createTree(data)

console.log(tree)
```